# Modify message with an Outlook web add-in (when reading email, not composing)

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to establish if this is even possible:

Can an outlook web add-in (i.e. a JavaScript add-in that works on the web and in outlook, not a COM based add-in) modify the body of an email while in read mode (i.e. the user is reading an email, not composing a new email or replying to an email).

What I need to do is trigger the add-in if the email contains hyperlinks (looks like I can do that with a contextual add-in using a regular expression) and then modify those hyperlinks (change the href or add an onClick event handler) so if the user clicks them the behaviour is different.

Comment: Currently we don't support any api which can set the body in read mode, as an alternative you can try the solution suggested below.

Comment: That's a shame @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, we wanted to add a warning message to our users if they were visiting a non-whitelisted website (trying to stop phishing attempts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT comment I'll post my own answer:

> You cannot modify the body of an email in read mode.

:(

Answer (score 1):

Cant comment. Not enough rep.

I am looking at the documentation for [Read Scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/read-scenario) I dont see anything related to set property.

However I do see something about extracting info from an item, more importantly [extracting URL's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/extract-entity-strings-from-an-item#extracting-urls)

May be you can extact URL's do your modifications and with the new content you can create a [New message item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox#displaynewmessageformparameters) or even [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item#displayreplyformformdata-callback) and [Reply all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item#displayreplyallformformdata-callback)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the modifications need to happen to the inbound email in the reading pane.

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to do that using calling UpdateItem via EWS from the add-in, right? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updateitem-operation
Why wouldn't that work @microsoft?